# Regular expressions - check if a match is contained within a textarea?

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a system whereby everything visible to the user is translatable. This means that every paragraph, title, link text, tooltip etc is contained in a database table and I am using tags to get the data. For example `[Tag 1]` may be Login or it could be changed to something else - it's definable by the company itself.

I have this working perfectly. I am overriding the Render method in the Page class to replace all these tags. I have a regex to match all tags in the format `[tag x]` where x is 1 or more numbers, i.e. the ID of the translation in the database; the regex I am using is `@"\[(Text|Tag) ([0-9]*)]`.

The problem I am having is that, for example, if you have a tag within a tag - for example `[tag 69]` is defined as `[tag 70][tag 71][tag 72]` - when the text is inside a textarea it is still replaced, so tag 69 will appear as the other 3 put together. I'd like to prevent replacements on tags contained within textareas. My first thought was that this would be easy - but then I realised that if you had `<textarea>[tag 1]</textarea>[tag 2]<textarea>[tag 3]</textarea>`, tag 2 would not be replaced.

I have to admit I am no pro at regular expressions - I would like to be but I don't have the time on my hands at the moment. Can anyone suggest a way that I could achieve what I'd like to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is how to match a `[Tag n]` that isn't enclosed inside a textarea? You can use a negative look-behind for that.

```
(?<!\<textarea\>)\[(tag|text) [0-9]+\]
```

The code:

```
var input = "<textarea>[tag 1]</textarea>[tag 2]<textarea>[tag 3]</textarea>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\<textarea\>)\[(tag|text) [0-9]+\]");

var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Outputs:

```
[tag 2]
```

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that this works on the string I gave as the example; however for some reason it doesn't work when the entire page html is given as the input string for String.Replace. It appears to throw a FormatException. I will work on this and post my solution. +1 for the answer.

Comment: Well I resolved the format exception (it was due to calling match.groups[a group number which didn't exist]), and also found another issue.. In replacing my code with your code I had removed the RegexOptions.IngoreCase, so it was only matching 4 tags in the entire page. Took me ages to figure this out but it works perfectly now! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, I have the following Regex now: `@"(?<!\<textarea class='tag'\>)\[(tag|text) ([0-9]+)\]"`. What if I wanted to include any attributes for the textarea, such as rows, id etc? I have tried changing it to `@"(?<!\<textarea(.*?)\>)\[(tag|text) ([0-9]+)\]"` but it does not work as expected. Any tags between the first opening textarea tag and the last closing one are not replaced. Any thoughts on this?