# Regular expressions - check if a match is not contained in a textarea

Tags: c#, regex

OK, so I opened up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373361/regular-expressions-check-if-a-match-is-contained-within-a-textarea) yesterday and got an answer fairly quickly. It worked, or so I thought, so I marked it as the correct answer.

However I don't think I explained the situation very well. Basically I am getting the HTML right before it is rendered, parsing it and searching for strings matching the pattern `[tag|text x]`, where x is a number and the two words are case-insensitive.

However, as stated in the previous question, I would like to NOT replace these tags if they're inside a textarea. This means that if they're between `</textarea>` and `<textarea...>` then I would still like to replace them, but if they're between `<textarea...>` and `</textarea>` then I would NOT like to replace them.

So far I have

```
@"(?<!\<textarea class='tag'\>)\[(tag|text) ([0-9]+)\]"
```

I have tried

```
@"(?<!\<textarea.[^>]*\>)\[(tag|text) ([0-9]+)\]"
```

but that doesn't appear to work either.

For example I would like to replace any tags outside of the textareas in the following:

```
[tag 1]
<textarea>[tag 2]</textarea>[tag 3]
<textarea class="bob">Walter [tag 4]</textarea>[tag 5]
<textarea attr-1="fred">Jim [tag 6] Mary</textarea>[tag 7]
[tag 8]
```

In this example only tags 1, 3, 5, 7 and 8 should be replaced; 2, 4 and 6 should not.

Does anyone have any idea how what I should change it to in order to achieve this? I am not asking for anyone to just do all the work for me and give me the answer - I am in this to learn. I have struggled with this for a few hours now so any assistance with this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing is usually easier to do with lookaheads than lookbehinds.  This works as you requested:

```
@"\[(tag|text)\s+(\d+)\](?![^<]*(?:<(?!/?textarea\b)[^<]*)*</textarea>)"
```

The idea here is to look for a `</textarea>` tag, but only if you *don't* encounter a `<textarea...>` tag first--that's this part:

```
[^<]*(?:<(?!/?textarea\b)[^<]*)*</textarea>
```

Assuming the HTML is well formatted, that regex could only match inside a textarea element.  Putting it in a negative lookahead which is executed *after* the `[tag]` has been matched causes matches in textareas to be rejected.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Just what I was looking for. It also rejects tags within HTML tags inside the textareas too so it does more than I asked for (forgot to mention that they could take that form in the first place). I wish I could get regexes but I just can't quite get the knack of them. The HTML is currently well formatted but that's not to say they will be in the future, when the company I work for has control over them. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to modify the regex to exclude text inside spans with class 'noreplace'. However I have been unsuccessful. So far I have `\[(tag|text)\s+(\d+)\](?!(([^<]*(?:<(?!/?textarea\b)[^<]*)*</textarea>)|([^<]*(?:<(?!/?span\b)( class='noreplace')+[^<]*)*</span>)))`. If I remove the `( class='noreplace')+` then it works for all spans and text areas (as in it excludes them), I just can't add a class to it and get it to include all other spans. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out with this. Thank you.

Comment: That's a different problem, requiring a different approach.  Can there be other tags inside these `<span>` elements?  In particular, can there be other `<span>` elements?  How about other `<span>` elements with `class='noreplace'` attributes?  But this answer cannot be expanded to handle even the simplest of those cases.   If you post this as a new question (with exhaustive sample data), I'm sure we can up with a solution that handles both problems.

Comment: I've got it! All I have to do is create a new class, called 'disabled' or something, apply it to textareas and that sets all textareas to display so that the user does not think the text can be changed; i.e. no border, transparent background, same style font etc. That would give the same effect as putting it in a span and would mean I don't have to go to the trouble of getting another regex!